# Laravel change default path

Tags: laravel-5

I downloaded a laravel project and install on my ubuntu into following default path var/www/html/timecapture/public

Now when I visit the path www.domain.com/timecapture/public then it works. Only the links im my application for example "employe" are showing to
www.domain.com/employe and not www.domain.com/timecapture/public/employee. 
Where can I do the necessary change?
I am using laravel 5.4.
thanks.

Comment: try making a virtual host in your ubuntu pointing laravel public folder

Answer (score 1):

You should change the DocumentRoot of your website in the configuration of apache, you can set it to the absolute path of your public folder (var/www/html/timecapture/public)